# Band-pass filtering on whole signal or overlapping chunks?

Tags: stft, filtering, window

I am working with a signal acquired by a pulse oximeter, i.e. a device that records the change of light intensity reflected by a specific tissue depending on its blood perfusion.

Since I am interest in the heart rate whose physiological frequency is in between let's say 30 beats per minute up to 300, I would like to bandpass filter my signal (especially high pass to remove baseline wandering).

My goal is to extract the heart rate in 10 seconds long windows. Should I apply frequency based filtering (bandpass) on the whole signal on on each 10 second chunk separately?

Many thanks :-)

Comment: How long is the signal typically? and the overlap?

Comment: A typical signal can be several minutes long. The overlap of the windows (signal chunks) is 7 seconds. Thus the 10s window is shifted by 3s at every step.